# How to find SharePoint site in IIS?

Tags: site-collection, site, server-farm, iis7

I have created multiple SharePoint sites in local Sharepoint Server (farm).

When I Open the IIS, I am not able to see any WebSite which is created in my sharepoint server.

So How can I find the existing sites in IIS ?

Answer (score 3):

when you create a webapplication in sparepoint central admin, you would then need to goto iis -> domain name -> click on "web sites".

You should be able to see a list of web applications e.g.

ssp.example.com

hello.example.com

test.example.com

that and oviously the correlating ip's and port number ect , as you can see its not sites or site collections that you can view here... only web application lists

for site collections and sites within the site collection goto:

2007

central admin -> application managment -> Site collection list

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc287826(v=office.12).aspx

2010

> 1.
>   Verify that the user account that is performing this procedure is a member of the Farm Administrators SharePoint group.
>
> 2.
>   On the Central Administration Home page, click Application Management.
>
> 3.
>   On the Application Management page, in the Site Collections section, click View all site collections. The page lists site
>   collections for the Web application that is displayed in the Web
>   Application drop-down menu.
>
> 4.
>   If the Web application for which you want to view site collections is not listed, click the down-arrow on the Web Application menu, and
>   then click Change Web Application. In the Select Web Application
>   dialog box, click the name of the Web application that you want.
>
> A list of all site collections that are associated with the Web application is displayed. The site collections are listed in
>   alphabetical order, in groups of 10 site collections per page.
>
> 5.
>   To view the details of a listed site collection, click the URL of the site collection in the URL column of the page (for example,
>   /mysites or /sites/team).
>
> 6.
>   When you have finished viewing site collections, click OK.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc287826(v=office.14).aspx

Answer (score 1):

In IIS you can find only web application. The sites that you creates in this application are stored in the content data base of SharePoint. You can use central administration to see and manage them.

Answer (score 0):

An IIS website is mapped to a SharePoint web application and not sites.So, for every web application you create on your WFE, you will be able to find the corresponding IIS websites (normally under C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories[port-no])